# HKLiveWorkoutDataSource - how to track ElevationAscended and ElevationDescended?

Tags: swift, iphone, apple-watch, healthkit

I see in documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyelevationascended that elevation ascended/descended is tracked automatically for HKWorkoutActivityType.snowboarding and ActivityType.downhillSkiing. How to track it for other types of activities like hiking?

e.g. for steps I can add:

```
liveworkout.enableCollection(for: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!, predicate: nil)
```

but I don't see to do something similar for for altitude.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't done automatically for other workouts. But you can track the user's location and use the [altitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude) property in `CLLocation` objects to calculate elevation ascended/descended. And then save it as metadata on the workout.